# Generate fixed number of results meeting some condition

Tags: julia, generator

Is there a way to call a function repeatedly, until a certain amount of results with certain attributes are collected?

#### Example:

Taking the function `rand()`, I want to keep only results that are above `>= 0.5` and generate 10 samples.

Of course I could do something like `rand(Truncated(Uniform(0,1), 0, 0.5), 10)` using the Distributions package, but I search a more abstract solution.

#### Not very satifsying solution:

So far I have only found the following:

```
using IterTools
cond(x) = ...
f() = ...
gen = IterTools.repeatedly(f)
samples = collect(IterTools.take((n for n in gen if cond(n)), size))
```

For the example above:

```
using Distributions
using IterTools
cond(x) = x >= 0.5
f() = rand(Uniform(0,1))
gen = IterTools.repeatedly(f)
rnd_nodes = collect(IterTools.take((n for n in gen if cond(n)), 10))
```

But is there maybe a shorter / concise / more readable way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to call a function repeatedly, until a certain amount of results with certain attributes are collected?

Sure, use a simple `while` loop.

```
using BenchmarkTools, Transducers

function loop()
    res = Vector{Float64}(undef,10)
    i = 0
    while i<10
        r = rand()
        if r >= 0.5
            i+=1
            res[i] = r
        end
    end
    return res
end

function transducer() # @Jun Tian's answer
    t = Map(_ -> rand()) |> Filter(x -> x >=0.5) |> Take(10)
    return collect(t, Iterators.repeated(1))
end

@btime transducer(); # 687ns
@btime loop(); # 170ns
@btime 0.5 .* rand(10) .+ 0.5; # 86ns
```

For comparison I added `0.5 .* rand(10) .+ 0.5` which just gives you what you want without iterating and relying on "luck".

Answer (score 0):

Try [Transducers.jl](https://github.com/tkf/Transducers.jl)

```
julia> using Transducers

julia> t = Map(_ -> rand()) |> Filter(x -> x >=0.5) |> Take(10)
Map(Main.λ❓) |>
    Filter(Main.λ❓) |>
    Take(10)

julia> collect(t, Iterators.repeated(1))
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6125615651973046
 0.9271858603504375
 0.8218768467739419
 0.5719380767545377
 0.7073831906599655
 0.5228490007486046
 0.9929437973392725
 0.6935716395158282
 0.6663379802812248
 0.6149007269488846
```